# how to return a normal array from PDO query?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm using PDO to access database  to retrieve values, but the returned array is messy. Is there a way that I could get the values and assign each one to a variables?

Here is my code :

```
$conn = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",
  $username, 
  $passwd, 
  array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
  )
);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM kanji WHERE wordid = 1 ');

$row = $result->fetchAll();
var_dump($row);
```

And here is the result :

```
    array(1) { [0]=> array(16) { ["wordid"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["audio"]=>
 string(38) "585c02afdc272d3a3473a888b9b185a4.mp3 " [1]=> string(38) 
"585c02afdc272d3a3473a888b9b185a4.mp3 " ["image"]=> string(23) "paste-5317169512449.jpg" 
[2]=> string(23) "paste-5317169512449.jpg" ["guess"]=> string(6) "okujou" [3]=> string(6) 
"okujou" ["kanji"]=> string(6) "屋上" [4]=> string(6) "屋上" ["fullword"]=> string(6) 
"okujou" [5]=> string(6) "okujou" ["vietnamese"]=> string(10) "roof,top " [6]=> string(10)
 "roof,top " ["example"]=> string(8) "屋上 " [7]=> string(8) "屋上 " } }
```

I want a result like `["wordid"]=> "1"` so I could you implode to assign each value to a variable.

Comment: Please read the fine manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php, specially following all explanations about the `fetch_style`.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php visit the link you'll get the answer

Comment: @deceze I read and tried all the style but it did not worked. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Then it's a good idea to include what you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `fetch_mode` in calls to `fetchAll`:

```
$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Alternatively use [setFetchMode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) to set the default fetch mode to use.

Comment: i used setFetchMode and it works! Thanks a lot, Jim!